# KeepassXC Autotype: Differ between "Return" and "Enter" key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keepass, keepassxc

I am using KeepassXC autotype to enter my credentials into a login mask. But this login mask differs between the <kbd>Return</kbd> and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. These are the relevant keys:

[image]

The KeepassXC autotype function only allows me to call "ENTER", but this actually triggers the <kbd>Return</kbd> key. In addition to the <kbd>Return</kbd> key in also need to be able to specifically call the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key next to the num block.

**Is there a way in the autotype function to call this key?**

Comment: That sounds like an XY problem. Are you by any chance trying to use KeePassXC's autotype for something different than it was designed for?

Comment: @gronostaj No, I need to login on a terminal screen and this differs between return and enter to login.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, KeePassXC uses the same autotype functions as KeePass.

KeePass documentation is quite extensive on the topic : https://keepass.info/help/base/autotype.html

Among other things, I can see on this page an example that should interest you :

> {VKEY 13}
> Presses and releases the primary Enter key. This is equivalent to {ENTER}.
> {VKEY 13 E}
> Presses and releases the Enter key of the numeric keypad.

Not sure whether it will fit your need from the first attempt, but that's probably something you would like to investigate